# Invalid real(datatype) error is occurring after I open my 837 Edi file in Edi Notepad

Tags: php, sql, edi

I am working on Edi project 837 which is used for claiming insurance so I created EDI file using PHP and SQL and to check I opened it in EDI Notepad Liaison. It showed error on some segments like CLM where amount of insurance is written which happened to be in decimals for eg.$250.85, and it said its invalid so I removed '$' sign but even after that it showed same error.
Error Occurred
**-Invalid real 250.85
  In segment CLM,BH**
When I manually removed decimals i.e when I wrote 250 the error didnt occurred but I want decimals too so how to remove this error?

Comment: Please, add all the relevant information in the question; not using a link/image.

Comment: what does Notepad show the element data type?  What version of the 837 are you using?

Comment: Notepad is not showing anything other than Error: Invalid real '250.85' so I am not sure about element datatype and version of 837 that I am using is 00501.